# Basic threading with single backgroundworker for multiple tasks

Tags: c#

I'd want to guarantee the order of execution in a single backgroundworker thread like this

```
One BackgroundWorker DoWork =
{
  First();
  Second();
  Third();
  ...
}

Function First()
{
   try{
      X();
      Y();
      Z(); //etc
   }catch
}
```

Comment: Look this:-https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/11/18/multithreading-in-winforms.aspx

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: @MichaelRandall, I'd want First() to execute then Second() then Third() inside a background worker thread.

Comment: You may want to use stateMachine?

Answer (score 1):

The question is marked for C#. Assuming the code is a representation of what you want to achieve in C# consider:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //If you need a return result
    //Task.FromResult(MainThread().ConfigureAwait(false)); 
    Task.Run(MainThread);
}

private async Task MainThread()
{
     var result1 = await Task1().ConfigureAwait(false);

     await Task2().ConfigureAwait(false);

     var result3 = await Task3().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private async Task<int> Task1()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Debug.WriteLine("Executed task 1");
    return 1;
}

private async Task Task2()
{
    await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Debug.WriteLine("Executed task 2");
}

private async Task<int> Task3()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Debug.WriteLine("Executed task 3");
    return 3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but is there any way to do this without spanning the duration set possible for a task.

Comment: the duration is probably there only as an example of "some long work happens", of course you shouldn't put any Delay but your actual work instead.

Comment: Da Wei, Pac0 is absolutely correct. I attempted to show tasks running at different intervals. Those delay tasks you will replace with whatever asynchronous functionality you require. Note that Task 1 runs 2000 milliseconds, Task 2 runs 100 milliseconds and Task 3 runs 1000 milliseconds. The await keyword ensured that the functionality completes sequentially. The output reads Executed task 1, Executed task 2 and Executed task 3 regardless of how long it takes to complete each task.